# The requested view was not found in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have my controller in the folder controllers with the name AdController
and my action name is

```
/**
 * action ajaxValue
 *
 * @param string $argument 
 * @return void
 */
public function ajaxValueAction($argument = NULL) {

 }
```

and my template file is on location Resources/Private/Templates/Ad/ajaxValue.html
with the name ajaxValue.html

```
{namespace t=Helhum\TyposcriptRendering\ViewHelpers}

<f:layout name="Default" />



This Template is responsible for creating a table of domain objects.

If you modify this template, do not forget to change the overwrite settings
in /Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml:
Resources:
Private:
Templates:
List.html: keep

Otherwise your changes will be overwritten the next time you save the extension in the extension builder

<f:section name="main">
    <f:debug title="Results of customers query">{ads}</f:debug>
    <f:flashMessages />

    <!-- Category selection box -->


    <!-- This is basically called a ajax request which is based on some other file take from the following link http://ajax.helmut-hummel.de/
```

-->

```
    <div id="dataJson" data-url="{t:uri.ajaxAction(action: 'ajaxValue', format: 'json', controller: 'Ad', pluginName: 'Txcasmarketing') -> f:format.htmlentities()}"></div>

    <div class="container">
         <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
                    <li>
                        <a data-catUid="{category.uid}" href="#">{category.name}</a>
                    </li>
                </f:for>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I am getting the following error

```
  <p><strong>Sorry, the requested view was not found.</strong></p> <p>The technical reason is: <em>No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "ajaxValue"  in class "CASmarketing\Casmarketing\Controller\AdController"</em>.</p>
```

The defaults templates which has been created by extension builder is accessible. the structure of my ex_localconf.php is

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        'CASmarketing.Casmarketing', 
        'Txcasmarketing', [
            'State' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
            'Category' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
            'Ad' => 'list, ajaxValue, show, new, create, edit, update, delete'
        ],
        // non-cacheable actions
        [
            'State' => 'create, update, delete',
            'Category' => 'create, update, delete',
            'Ad' => 'create, update, delete'
        ]
);
}, $_EXTKEY
);
```

and my template file is on location Resources/Templates/Ad/ajaxValue.html

with the name ajaxValue.html

and my step.ts file sitting is

```
 plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing {
     view {
  templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:casmarketing/Resources/Private/Templates/
  templateRootPaths.1 =              {
    $plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.view.templateRootPath}
   partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:casmarketing/Resources/Private/Partials/
  partialRootPaths.1 =   {
      $plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.view.partialRootPath}
   layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:casmarketing/Resources/Private/Layouts/
  layoutRootPaths.1 = {
 $plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.view.layoutRootPath}
 }
 persistence {
   storagePid = {
  $plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.persistence.storagePid}
  #recursive = 1
  }
 features {
  #skipDefaultArguments = 1
    }
   mvc {
     #callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
       }
          }
```

my script file which is basically called the ajax request which is define in the pageLayout.js

$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {

```
    var jsonUrl = $('#dataJson').attr('data-url')
    var selectedCatUid = $(this).attr('data-catUid');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: jsonUrl,
        data: {
            'tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing[catId]': selectedCatUid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
    });
```

Comment: I change it to capital it is still the same and i menioned my step.ts file. it does not accept any other action except then the defult which has been provided by extension builder???

Answer (score 1):

Your template should not be in `Resources/Templates/Ad/ajaxValue.html` but in `Resources/Private/Templates/Ad/AjaxValue.html`. Mind the **Private** sub folder. Also it has to be UpperCase.

Comment: it is already in the Resources/Private/Templates/Ad/AjaxValue.html may my mistake i did not mention that...

Comment: i explain further my problem may be it is more clear to you... i mention my template file

Comment: is it possible i can chat with you. you can see my problem exactly? it would be your kindness ...

Comment: You can always join the TYPO3 community on Slack and ask your questions in a more chatty manner there as long as you keep this question updated afterwards so the solution can persist.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know that it does matter but the filename usually is uppercase. You also should make sure that the typoscript settings are configured to this directory.

Comment: I change it to capital it is still the same and i menioned my step.ts file. it does not accept any other action except then the defult which has been provided by extension builder???

Comment: Your ext_localconf is correct otherwise you would get another error. Your typoscript syntax is wrong. The .1 is nested with  { but you can't do so because it is not a typoscript object with nesting you have to put in the path Directly.

Comment: Ah wait I see it is a constant but it has to be without spacing between the  {s

Comment: but it is working with default templates which is generated with extension builder. in my case the list.html extra is working perfactly. could you rewrite the suggested changes so i can clearly understand thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your typoscript should correctly look like this:

```
plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:casmarketing/Resources/Private/Templates/
    templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.view.templateRootPath}

    partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:casmarketing/Resources/Private/Partials/
    partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.view.partialRootPath}

    layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:casmarketing/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.view.layoutRootPath}
  }

  persistence {
    storagePid = {$plugin.tx_casmarketing_txcasmarketing.persistence.storagePid}
    #recursive = 1
  }

  features {
    #skipDefaultArguments = 1
  }

  mvc {
    #callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
  }
}
```

If you change this in your setup.txt of the extension this is hardly cached and you have to clear the cache in the install tool. After making sure your typoscript is correctly loaded place your new Views template inside the ext-directory template path first to try it out.

If this does not help please give us the content of your HTML Template.

Comment: My stepup.ts file is exactly written like, what did you mention in the up comments... there is nothing changed..... i can mention my template file. basically in List.html file there is option box which drop down and i select a value and then a ajax request is go to controller and the controller must to do a query to return a value to another template file or exactly same list.html with updated value. i can update my main question you can see the full description in how i call the controller from the list template.....